# Xamarin.Forms ImageCell not displaying image version 4.7.0.xx

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I already tried, `string` to `ImageSource` in my model but still I did not get image to display in ImageCell.

If I try this line of code `<Image Source="https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/user.png"></Image>`, image displays fine.

Model

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImageUri { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.ListPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}" TextColor="Accent" DetailColor="Beige"></TextCell>-->
                        <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}"></TextCell>-->
                        `<ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageUri}`"></ImageCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <!--<Image Source="https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/user.png"></Image>-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

XAML.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = new List<Contact>
        {
            new Contact{ Name="Monkey D. Luffy", ImageUri=ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/user.png"))},
            new Contact{ Name="Monkey D. Dragon",
                ImageUri=ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/user.png"))},
            new Contact{ Name="Portgas D. Ace",
                ImageUri=ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/2x/user.png")), Status="Hello World!"}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You can directly user `Image` instead of `ImageCell` inside your data template `ViewCell`.

Comment: What size of your image? I think you need to add `HasUnevenRows="true"` in your `ListView` your image look like hidden by row height

Comment: @cahyo ViewCell works, i dont know what is the problem with ImageCell

Comment: I update my xamarin forms nuget package to the `4.7.0.1179`, Here is my test image:https://aka.ms/campus.jpg, this image is a big, but waitting for serveral seconds. it work as normal.https://imgur.com/a/UovlCAs  You can use my  image url to make a test, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

just did two tests on my playground.

I kicked off with a blank Xamarin.Forms project (only one MainPage there) in VS2019, then

1. updated the XF nuget package to 4.7.0.1142.
2. pasted your code.
3. remove two extra `` ` `` characters in your xaml code snippet.

It's working.

Then, I tried the string property in the model class like this:
`public string ImageUri { get; set; }`
And also set string value in xaml.cs class like this:
`new Contact{ Name="", ImageUri="https://xxx.png"}`

[image]

It's also working.

Not sure about the issue, but your code is fine anyway.

Comment: this weird, already created new project to try, still no display. already clear bin,obj files. I but using ViewCell image works, im debugging using my mobile phone.

Comment: @CoffeeCode, I was using my android phone too, how about the Android OS version. And when you mentioned 4.7.x there, does that mean you can see the pics on 4.6.x? (For testing, you can always leave the Image outside the listview uncommented, to exclude other possibilities, like network error). And I'm using VS2019 on win10, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this nuget https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading for images. Is the best !!